# Sum (binary) pixels within a fixed-size region centered at *each and every* pixel

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

Given an `HxW` binary image (represented as a numpy 2d array) and `D` (integer), I would like to output another `HxW` 2d array in which each `(i, j)` index stores the number of `1` pixels in the binary image which are at most `D` rows or columns (basically, up to `D` pixels away in the L1 sense) from `(i, j)`.

I can of course achieve this by convolving the binary image with a `DxD` all-ones square, but that seems rather slow using `scipy.signal.convolve2d`, for example. Also, my `D` can be rather large (e.g. 256 for an image of size 2600x1900). Any other suggestions?

Comment: [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) may be faster for larger arrays. I'm kind of surprised that scipy doesn't automatically check.

Comment: Convolving with a square kernel with uniform weights can be done really cheaply (in O(1) per pixel, independently of the size of the kernel) using the integral image (cumulative sum in both directions). I suggest you google that, I’m sure it’ll be easy to find a good description.

Comment: I thought about using integral image but only when you mentioned it it actually "clicked" and I know now how can I use it: calculate integral image and then do a diff between the integral image and its (D, D) forward-shifted version. That will give me in each each pixels the number of non-zero pixels in the DxD block preceding it.

Answer (score 1):

A DxD square is a [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter) filter kernel -- convolving an image with a DxD square of 1s is the same as convolving each row with a row of D 1s, and then convolving each column of the result with a column of D 1s.  That reduces the problem from O(H * W * D * D) to O(H * W * D).

But a 1d convolution with a row or column of D 1s can be implemented as a (single stage) [cascaded integrator-comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascaded_integrator%E2%80%93comb_filter) filter. That reduces the problem complexity from O(H * W * D) to O(H * W).

Computationally, this is similar to what @Cris Luengo suggests in comments, but it can be implemented in place without extra memory.

Comment: I've used scipy.signal.oaconvolve ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.oaconvolve.html#scipy-signal-oaconvolve)) and it was much faster than a plain convolution. Does it do something similar to what you suggested (integrator-comb)?

Comment: No, oaconvolve is an FFT-based method.  Not nearly as fast as this answer, but it works for arbitrary filters. O(H * W * log(D)), and for large filter kernels it's faster than brute force.